# WP_Query вывести записи со всеми значениями, если не указано иное

Tags: php, wordpress

Из формы в цикл `wp_query();` передается значения мета-полей записи, по которым нужно сделать выборку, то есть, упрощенно

```
'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'key1',
            'value' => $_GET['value1'],
            ),
        array(
            'key' => 'key2',
            'value' => $_GET['value2'],
            ),
)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы, если передано пустое значение, выдавались записи с любым значением этого поля, то есть сменить на

```
'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'key1',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                ),
            array(
                'key' => 'key2',
                'value' => $_GET['value2'],
                ),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Определяем массив как переменную, и, в зависимости от переданных данных, отправляем в массив агрументов

```
if (!empty($_GET["key1"])) {
    $key = array(
        'key' => 'key1',
        'value' => $_GET['value1']
        );
} else {
    $key = array(
        'key' => 'key1',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        );
}



'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            $key
)
```